# Disassociate my phone number from Facebook

Tags: facebook, phone-number, facebook-account

The person who had my phone number before me had it associated with Facebook. I am constantly getting SMS notifications from Facebook about his account. I don't have access to his account to remove the phone number.

How can I disassociate my phone number from his account without having access to his account?

Comment: @pnuts - the owner of what? facebook? afaik mark zuckerburg doesn't take personal calls. there is no donor or seller involved. i'm not sure what i can add to make the question more clear.

Comment: @pnuts - correct. you're suggesting i contact the phone company? what would i ask, for them to block facebook?

Comment: yea but that's a pretty extreme measure and I run the risk of getting another number that is associated with someone else's fb account